# Identity little brown lady bugs taking shelter in my home

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Can someone please identify this little creature for me. They are appearing more frequently in my room. What are they doing here? Could it be those basic needs and requirements?

The size is about 2 x 1 millimetre. My location is the Netherlands. I am on the 20th floor of a flat. The season is now heading towards end of spring.

[image]

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include the size of the insect as well as your location and season?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, description updated. Getting all biological now hehe